# Writing Excel sql via adodb connection

Tags: sql, excel, adodb

I have the following sql syntax submitted via adodb connection

select aa, bb, cc from [sheet1$]

where cc column field is a value/blank

however when the sql syntax being run, I find the result in column cc returned back a datetime value format to me and when I change the column cc(cells) format to "General", the result returns not the true value it returns for instance if the value is 3.56, it got 2.56

how can I fix it, thanks a lot

Comment: What data type is cc? Is the entire column full of blank values/nulls? (In which case, there is little point in importing it.)

Comment: rows may be nulls/values

Comment: What values? What data type?

Comment: data type is float